# Problem invoving 3 sequences and square roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$,$(b_n)_{n \ge 0}$,$(c_n)_{n \ge 0}$ be three sequences of positive numbers such that $a_0,b_0,c_0 \gt 0$. The sequence satisfies the reccurence relation in the picture. Show that the sequences have the same finite limit and compute it.

[image]